# Itō formula as presented in "Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions" by Giuseppe Da Prato

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

In [Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/stochastic-equations-infinite-dimensions), [Theorem 4.32 (Google Books)](https://books.google.de/books?id=H-VSAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=Theorem+4.32%22+%22under+the+above+conditions%22&source=bl&ots=u8gTgwVrgl&sig=0RT2GfrSlGxmWG2glxquWdl5flo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii162B6qnMAhUGDZoKHTxHA2wQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Theorem%204.32%22%20%22under%20the%20above%20conditions%22&f=false), the authors present the following version of an Itō formula:

> Given Hilbert spaces $(U,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U)$ and $(H,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle)$, a $U$-valued Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ and $$X_t=X_0+\int_0^t\varphi_s\;{\rm d}s+\int_0^t\Phi_s\;{\rm d}W_s\tag 1$$ for some $H$-valued random variable $X_0$, $H$-valued stochastic process $(\varphi_t)_{t\ge 0}$ and $\mathfrak L(U,H)$-valued$^1$ stochastic process $(\Phi_t)_{t\ge 0}$, we've got
>
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> f(t,X_t)-f(0,X_0)&=\color{red}{\int_0^t\langle\Phi_s{\rm d}W_s,F_x(s,X_s)\rangle}\\
> &\quad\color{blue}{+\text{something unimportant for this question}}
> \end{split}\tag 2
> \end{equation}
>
> for all $F:[0,\infty)\times H\to\mathbb R$ with partial Fréchet derivatives $F_t$, $F_x$ and $F_{xx}$.

**Question**: What's the definition of the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term? (They don't give one in the book).

The proof of the statement can be reduced to the case $\varphi_t=\varphi_0$ and $\Phi_t=\Phi_0$. If $0=t_0<\cdots<t_n=t$ is a partition of $[0,t]$, Taylor's theorem yields$^2$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(t,X_t)-f(0,X_0)&=\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n\langle\Delta X_i,L_i\rangle}\\
&\quad\color{blue}{+\text{something unimportant for this question}}
\end{split}\tag 3
\end{equation}

where $\Delta t_i=t_i-t_{i-1}$, $\Delta X_i=X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}$ and $$L_i:=F_x(t_{i-1},X_{t_{i-1}})\;.$$ Using $(1)$ and our assumption, the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term in $(3)$ is $$\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n\langle\Phi_0\Delta W_i,L_i\rangle}\color{blue}{+\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta t_i\langle\varphi_0,L_i\rangle}\tag 4\;.$$ Using the definition of the adjoint operator, the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term in $(4)$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^n\langle\Delta W_i,\Phi_0^\ast L_i\rangle_U\;.\tag 5$$ In the middle of page 108 they state (our $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term from $(3)$ is called $I_2$ there) that $(5)$ converges almost surely to $$\int_0^t\langle\Phi_s{\rm d}W_s,F_x(s,X_s)\rangle\tag 6$$ for $n\to\infty$.

> Why?

---

$^1$ Let $\mathfrak L(A,B)$ be the space of bounded, linear operators $A\to B$.

$^2$ Notice that we can make sense of $(3)$, since $L_i\in\mathfrak L(H,\mathbb R)\cong H$ by [Riesz' representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean. I will answer it.

Answer (score 2):

There is exactly a definition of the term $\int_0^t\langle\Phi_s{\rm d}W_s,F_x(s,X_s)\rangle$.

For $\Phi_s$ taking values in $\mathfrak L_2(Q^\frac{1}{2}U,H)$ and satisfying the condition that the integral of $\Phi_s$-'s square-norm in $\mathfrak L_2(Q^\frac{1}{2}U,H)$ is a.s. finite (just called the "Energe Condition" privately), and for $\Psi_s$ a $H$-valued process, one can prove that the process $\Phi_s^*\Psi_s$ defined by
$$(\Phi_s^*\Psi_s)(u)=\langle\Phi_su,\Psi_s\rangle\quad\text{for }u\in Q^\frac{1}{2}U$$
has values in $\mathfrak L_2(Q^\frac{1}{2}U,\mathbb R)$ and satisfies the Energe Condition. Hence we can define
$$\int_0^t\langle\Phi_s{\rm d}W_s,\Psi_s\rangle:=\int_0^t(\Psi_s^*\Phi_s){\rm d}W_s.$$

I don't know whether there is any comment like above in Prato's book, yet it is noted in another reference book --- "[Stochastic Differential Equations in Infinite Dimensions](https://books.google.com/books?hl=zh-CN&lr=&id=yqlcgl3KumQC&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=Stochastic+Differential+Equations+in+Infinite+Dimensions++Gawarecki+&ots=xF83rrcCTD&sig=Hkplcf4CgRlP89iXdkblqbl_cDM#v=onepage&q=Stochastic%20Differential%20Equations%20in%20Infinite%20Dimensions%20%20Gawarecki&f=false)" by L. Gawarecki & V. Mandrekar, in page 61.

Comment: Is $\Phi_s^\ast$ supposed to be the adjoint operator of $\Phi_s$? If that's the case, I'm confused, since $\Phi_s^\ast$ is an element of $\mathfrak L(H,Q^{\frac 12}U)$ and $\Psi_s\in H$, we've got $\Phi_s^\ast\Psi\in Q^{\frac 12}U$. So, the left-hand side of your first centered equation doesn't make sense.

Comment: I could imagine that you use that $U_0:=Q^{\frac 12}U$ can be identified with its topological dual space $U_0'$ such that we can consider $\Phi_s^\ast\Psi$ as being an element of $U_0'=\mathfrak L(U_0,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d $Q^\frac{1}{2}U$ is also a Hilbert space. To be specific, the equation means $(\Phi_s^*\Psi_s)(u)=\langle\Phi_s^*\Psi_s,u\rangle_{Q^\frac{1}{2}U}=\langle\Phi_su,\Psi_s\rangle_H$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d By the way, if confusing, just put aside the subject of Hilbert space, and regard $\Phi_s^\ast$ as an element in $\mathfrak L(H^\ast,(Q^{\frac 12}U)^\ast)$.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but written an own one. Please take note of that answer; maybe you can help with the remaining problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Let me split this answer into two parts:

### Part 1

Let $U$ and $H$ be arbitrary Hilbert spaces, $L\in\mathcal L(U,H)$ and $x\in H$. As [Q. Huang](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/329754/q-huang) noted in his answer, the authors of [Stochastic Differential Equations in Infinite Dimensions](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642161933)$^3$ "define" $$(L^\ast x)u:=\langle Lu,x\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }u\in U\;.\tag 7$$ I hate that, it's awful. Why? Well, cause by definition of the [adjoint operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint), $$\langle Lu,x\rangle_H=\langle u,L^\ast x\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U\tag 8$$ and by [Riesz’ representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem)$^4$, $\exists!T\in U'$ with $$Tu=\langle u,L^\ast x\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U\;.\tag 9$$ Thus, $L^\ast x\in U$ can be identified with $T\in\mathfrak L(U,\mathbb R)$. So, the mapping defined by $(7)$ equals $T$. I hate $(7)$, cause it redefines the symbol sequence $L^\ast x$, wresting the meaning of the individual symbols and hides what actually is going on.

So, with $U$ and $H$ be separable, $Q\in\mathfrak L(U)$ being nonnegative and symmetric with finite trace, $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$ and $(\Phi_t)_{t\ge 0}$ being $\operatorname{HS}(U_0,H)$-valued, they define $$\int_0^t\langle\Phi_s{\rm d}W_s,\varphi_s\rangle_H:=\int_0^t\langle\;\cdot\;,\Phi_s^\ast\varphi_s\rangle_{U_0}{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge 0\;.\tag{10}$$ However, I'm sure we can make sense of the equality in $(1)$ without defining it (any related comment is welcome).

### Part 2

I think that the considerations above and the definition of $(10)$ in the book is needlessly complicated. Since $L_1,\ldots,L_n\in\mathfrak L(H,\mathbb R)$ and (see [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758340/approximation-of-int-0tf-xs-x-s%CE%A6-0dw-s-where-dx-s-%CF%86-sds%CE%A6-sdw-s-and-f-x) I will mention in a moment) $$L_i\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\Phi_s\;{\rm d}W_s=\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}L_i\Phi_s\;{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}\;,\tag{11}$$ we can conclude that $$S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nL_i(\Phi_0\Delta W_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nL_i\left(\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\Phi_0\;{\rm d}W_s\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}L_i\Phi_0\;{\rm d}W_s\;.$$

> If we can show (and I hope that we can) that $$\operatorname P\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\int_0^tF_x(s,X_s)\Phi_0\;{\rm d}W_s\right]=1\;,\tag{12}$$ we would be done with the proof of this special case and would not need an extra definition for the term $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to.

I've asked for $(12)$ in a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758340/approximation-of-int-0tf-xs-x-s%CE%A6-0dw-s-where-dx-s-%CF%86-sds%CE%A6-sdw-s-and-f-x).

---

$^3$ While this book has the same title as the book in the question, they are different.

$^4$ $U'=\mathfrak L(U,\mathbb R)$ is the [topological dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Continuous_dual_space) of $U$.